# How do I get rid of the entire row when I dismiss a bootstrap alert?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an alert within a row-fluid. See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2764/show/). When I dismiss the alert with the "x" button, the row still is visible. How do I get rid of the entire row when I dismiss it? I've tried:

```
data-dismiss="row-fluid"
```

which doesn't let me close anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a solution that wouldn't involve a tiny bit of jQuery.  If you can use jQuery, then the solution below would work.

Attach a function to the click event that hides the row.  (I added the class "error" so that I could select just that row).

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2765/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid error" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="span4">
            <div class="alert">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
              <strong>Warning!</strong> Best check yo self, you're not looking too good.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row-fluid" style="border:1px solid red;">
        <div class="span12">
            this is some other content
        </div>
    </div>

</div>​
<script>
    $('.close').click(function(){
        $(".row-fluid.error").hide()
    });
</script>
```